# What is the maximum size of a zip file on Windows 10 Pro 64-Bit?

Tags: windows, windows-10, zip

I just created a zip folder of my Pictures folder using `Send to -> Compressed (zipped) folder`, and it is 44 GBs.  I can view files and it seems to be okay, however, I just read that the limit might be 4 GBs. What is the maximum size of a zip file if the OS is 64-bit Windows 10 Pro?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

4 GB size is a limitation for an old zip format. 
And it is a limit for any file on FAT32 disks.
A modern version of ZIP is almost unlimited (it has about 16 exabytes size limitation).

Comment: Thanks Michael.  Wow, an exabyte is pretty big!  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exabyte

Comment: correct answer, but I think it would be better with a (reputable) source: maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Limits , which lists http://www.artpol-software.com/ZipArchive/KB/0610051629.aspx as its source, respectively.

Comment: @flolilolilo Wikipedia can be modified to say anything best to quote the sources in a Wikipedia article. (Not saying Wikipedia isn’t correct) but trust but verify.